# Laravel smtp gmail connection refused on live server

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, gmail

Laravel `7.24`.

PHP `7.2.5`.

I have setup emailing but it is not working on live server BUT it is working locally fine don't know why ?

Here is some point that I've tried but still not working,

`php artisan config:clear`

`tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587`

`tcp://smtp.gmail.com:465`

`ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465`

[image: Exception]

I also tried `ping smtp.gmail.com`,

[image: ping]

I have also setup app_key from gmail with 2 step verification.

Is server having some problem or php.ini ?

Kindly help me!

Comment: does it work with https://mailtrap.io ?

Comment: @sta I didn't checked yet!

Comment: May be your hosting provider blocks those smtp port, in this case you need to tell them to unblock those port

Comment: Do I check that with cPanel or SSH ?

Comment: Hope this helps https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360041074753-Why-is-port-25-blocked-

Comment: `curl smtp.gmail.com:587` showing "curl: (7) couldn't connect to host". Is that the issue ?

Comment: Yes, your hosting provider block that port. Make a support ticket to unblock that. Also try with another port

Comment: Okay thank you so much @sta. So I have to ask them to enable `587` port right ?

Comment: Exactly, tell them to unblock 465 and 587 port :)

Comment: Okay thank you you saved my time :)